# Mapping and filtering a list of maybes with a maybe returning function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, option-type

I have a list of maybes and a function that gives me a node's color (if present):

```
maybeNeighbors :: [Maybe Node]
nodeColor      :: Node -> Maybe Color
```

Now I'd like to map colors to nodes, and as intermediate step I want to have a list of tuples:

```
coloredList    :: [(Color, [Node])]
```

(Because I'll construct a Map from it later with `listToUFM_C (++) listColored`)

Here is what I have so far, it works but seems ugly:

```
listColored    =  mapMaybe (\n -> nodeColor n >>= \c -> Just (c, [n])) $ catMaybes maybeNeighbors
```

(using `catMaybes` and `mapMaybe` from Data.Maybe)

I feel like I'm missing something, that I should be able to do something like `(fmap . fmap) func maybeNeighbors`, but I can't figure out how `func` should look like.
Or a function like this, which I can't find either: `(Maybe a -> Maybe b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]`

**Edit:**

I'm working on a graph coloring problem and I want a list of nodes that have the same color. Here is an example to test in GHCi:

```
let l = [Just (1, Just 'a'), Just (2, Just 'a'), Nothing, Just (3, Just 'b'), Just (4, Nothing)]
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing, but I believe you should be able to skip the `catMaybes` step by changing the function argument to `mapMaybe`.

Comment: That last signature is just `map`. You should construct the `Map` directly, rather than a list of k,v pairs.

Comment: Extending what @dfeuer says: `mapMaybe (>>= nodeColor) maybeNeighbors`

Comment: @SimonShine But that wouldn't that just give me a list of colors? I want to know which nodes have the same color.

Comment: @moonGoose That's true, so I guess that's not what I want. I need to filter out two layers of Nothing (No node, no color). That's why I don't see how I can construct the Map directly.

Comment: Simon Shine's answer (`fromListWith (++)`) is what I had in mind, sorry if it wasn't clear. The cleanest way using (semi-)standard functions to collapse&remove two layers of `Maybe` is with relude's `traverseToFst` - `mapMaybe (traverseToFst nodeColor =<<) :: [Maybe Node] -> [(Color, Node)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like it would be expressed the cleanest as a list comprehension:

```
listColored = 
    [ (c, [n])
    | Just n <- maybeNeighbors
    , Just c <- [nodeColor n]
    ]
```

Inside a list comprehension, a pattern-match failure will result in just skipping the element, so you'll naturally get rid of `Nothing`s in `maybeNeighbors` as well as `Nothing` outputs from `nodeColor`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're making a function `[Maybe Node] -> Map Color [Node]`?

```hs
colorMap :: [Maybe Node] -> Map Color [Node]
colorMap = Map.fromListWith (++) . listColored

listColored :: [Maybe Node] -> [(Color, [Node])]
listColored = mapMaybe $ \maybeNode -> do
  node <- maybeNode
  color <- nodeColor node
  pure (color, [node])
```

**Edit:** Isolating the `listColored` part for better comparison with Fyodor's list comprehension.

Comment: That's also a very good answer. In this case I'm going with Fyodor Soikin's, because it is more terse and `listColored` is already one let-binding of many in a bigger function.

Comment: I meant without constructing the key-value pairs of the map; here you're inserting in the map to combine ie. not constructing the resulting pair directly.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer: In that case I provided a `listColored` for better comparison, since my intent was to show a `do` version for comparison with Fyodor's list comprehension. :-) The terser alternative to `do` that I can think of is a bunch of compressed, explicit `>>=`s.